# Line7:1: parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level

Tags: reactjs, import, components

My code throws the error

```
parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level
```

What could be the problem? My code:

```
import React from "react";

function Address(){

let Adress = "96 rue de la bonheur,Casa";
return(

<p>MyAddress:<br/>{Adress}</p>

)
export default Address;
}
```

Comment: the error message says, it doesn't like the export statement on your almost-last-line. You can only use import and export outside of functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import React from "react";

function Address(){

let Adress = "96 rue de la bonheur,Casa";
return(
<div>

  {Adress}
</div>
) }
export default Address;
```